# Как не всовывать лишнее в масив со скаляра?

Tags: perl

```
$words = param("words");
$words = q[ a df

   b

c  ];
```

Нужно что б в масиве осталось

```
@mass = ("a df", "b", "c");
```

то есть надо удалить пробелы с начала и с конца и пустые строки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@mass = map { s/^\s+//;s/\s+$//;$_ } grep { /\S/ } split /\n/, $words
```

Comment: спасибо!
пол дня бился.
копал где то в эту сторону но в воедино собрать не мог...

Answer (score -1):

```
$words = param("words");
```

А вот это вообще лишнее)) Дальше ведь присваивание идёт...